# How to use the "File Check" option of BMG(BOOTSTRAPPER MANIFEST GENERATOR) tool to check if the preRequisite is already installed on the system?

Tags: c#, setup-project, setup-deployment, setuptools, prerequisites

Hi I am using BMG (Bootstrpper Manifest Generator) tool to package a  custom "PREREQUISITE" application, which can be installed prior to  installation of a set up project application. 
       But I want to check if the prerequisite application already exists or not before beginning the installation.

> It dawned on me that this can be
>   achieved by using "File Check" option
>   in BMG(Bootstrapper Manifest
>   Generator).
>   **CAN ANYONE KINDLY LET ME KNOW HOW TO USE THE FILE CHECK OPTION OF "BMG TOOL".**

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 3):

The way I use it for Acrobat Reader X:

- go to the System Checks tab.
- click the File Check button.
- In "Property For Result", put an explanatory name (ex: 'AcrobatReader')
- In "File name to search for", put the name of the main executable file of the prerequesite application (ex. for Acrobat Reader: 'AcroRd32.exe').
- Optionally, check "Start Search in Special Folder", and select "ProgramFilesFolder" (supposing the prerequesite installs there).
- If you check it, put in Path the subfolder in wich the prerequesites is installed (ex. for Acrobat Reader: Adobe\Reader 10.0\Reader)
- In Search Depth, put 0 if you want to search in every subfolder, or any number if you want to stop at a certain depth. 0 by default.
- Go to the Install Conditons tab.
- In the first line, column Type, choose ByPassIf
- column Property, choose the name of your previously created Property For Result (in this case, AcrobatReader).
- in the third column, choose 'Exists'.

You can also do something equivalent for registry keys, check versions...